# Why is a CSV file derived from a WAV file so much bigger than the original WAV file?

Tags: python, csv, scipy, wav

I've used the *read* function from *scipy.io.wavfile* followed by *numpy.array* and *numpy.savetxt* to convert a WAV file into a vector stored in CSV. Like this:

```
def read_wav(wav_file_name):
    a = read('data/'+wav_file_name)
    b = numpy.array(a[1],dtype=float)
    numpy.savetxt('data/'+wav_file_name+'.csv', b, delimiter=",")
    return b
```

However, the CSV file is now 6.2MB while the WAV file was only 490kB. How is that possible? A single vector should be smaller in my mind?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`np.savetxt()` will convert what was previously a compact `int` or `float` representation of a series of numbers into an ASCII representation of them. For example, `np.savetxt('test.txt', np.arange(10), delimiter=",")` creates a 250-byte text file that looks like:

```
0.000000000000000000e+00
1.000000000000000000e+00
2.000000000000000000e+00
...
```

Assuming each of the numbers was originally represented as a 32-bit float, that would represent an increase from 40 bytes in memory to 250 bytes of text, or a ratio of 6.25.

Comment: Thanks! That makes sense. I now just use the `numpy.save` function to save it into a `.npy` file. It still increase the data size but it's a factor 3 smaller than when using `numpy.savetxt`.